# Integral domains $R$ such that any ring $R \subset S \subset K$ is Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, noetherian

Which integral domains $R$ with fraction field $K$ have the property that for any intermediate ring $R \subset S \subset K$, $S$ is Noetherian?

I'm not really good at naming things, but let's call such integral domains *fractionally-closed Noetherian* for short.

It's not difficult to see that any PID $R$ is fractionally-closed Noetherian, in fact, every subring of the fraction field of $R$ which contains $R$ is some localization of $R$.
I have been able to prove at least a partial converse: if $R$ is a fractionally-closed Noetherian gcd-domain, then $R$ is a PID. Here is the proof:

Let $R$ be a gcd-domain which is not a PID. If $R$ is not Noetherian, $R$ is certainly not fractionally-closed Noetherian, so we are done. Suppose $R$ is Noetherian. We may find $a',b' \in R$ such that $(a',b')$ is not a principal ideal. Write $d = \mathrm{gcd}(a',b'), a' = ad, b' = bd$, then we have $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$ and $(d)(a,b)=(a',b')$ as ideals. If $(a,b)$ was principal, $(a',b')$ would be principal as well, so $(a,b)$ is not principal. Consider the ring

$S:=bR_a+R = \{b\frac{r_1}{a^n}+r_2|r_1,r_2 \in R, n \in \mathbb N_0\}$.

In $S$, we have the increasing chain of ideals $(\frac{b}{a}) \subset (\frac{b}{a^2}) \subset \dots$ To see that this chain is in fact properly increasing, it suffices to show that $\frac{1}{a} \notin S$
Suppose $\frac{1}{a}=b\frac{r_1}{a^n}+r_2$, where we may choose $r_1$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(r_1,a)=1$. We must have $n \geq 1$, for else RHS is in $R$, but clearly $a$ is not a unit in $R$. Now $a^{n-1}-a^nr_2=br_1$. If $n=1$, this gives an easy contradiction as $(a,b) \neq (1)$, if $n \geq 2$, we get $a | br_1$, but we have $\mathrm{gcd}(a,br_1) = 1$ from $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(a,r_1)=1$.

So far, I have not found an example of fractionally-closed Noetherian integral domain which is not a PID, so one might as well suspect that any such domain is in fact a PID, but I have not been able to prove this either.

My questions is: Can you prove or disprove that any fractionally-closed Noetherian integral domain is a PID or give some interesting necessary or sufficient criteria?

Comment: Hint: Try to show that $\dim R\le 1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: @user26857 That would certainly be a satisfying solution. Do you have any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: If $\dim R\le 1$ then apply Krull-Akizuki.

Comment: For the converse, assume $\dim R\ge2$. Chose $(0)\subset P\subset M$ a chain of primes, $x\in P$, $x\ne0$, and $y\in M\setminus P$. Then study the ring $S=R[\frac{x}{y^n}:n>0]$.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks a lot, I think I can handle the rest. Do you want to post your hints as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Glad to help you.